# Why django models make many small queries instead of one large?

Tags: python, django

Sorry for non-specific problem, but i suppose this might be an interesting question. At least it is to me ;)

I am using django models to get data from few related tables at once. When the QuerySet is eveluated I'd rather expect django to make query like this one:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field1, t2.field2 FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON (t1.fk_t2 = t2.pk);
```

But instead of what I excpect, I can see Django doing something like this:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.fk_t2 FROM t1;
```

And then for all t1.fk_t2

```
SELECT t2.field1, t2.field2 FROM t2 WHERE id = (here comes some single id);
```

Is this default Django behavior? Why it acts like this? Is this more efficient? What came to my mind first, is that making JOIN requires doing cross join and then filtering very large table, when doing many single selects allows you to deal with no more data, than really required, but this is only an idea.

Anyone can explain? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django gets only the data you ask it to get. You can use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to ask it to get all the data in a single query using JOINs.

Quoting docs:

> select_related(*fields)
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow”
> foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data
> when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which
> results in a single more complex query but means later use of
> foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.
>
> prefetch_related(*lookups)
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically
> retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified
> lookups.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!